# How often to change Aprilaire AC Filter

Tags: hvac, central-air, air-filter

I have a AprilAire #2210 Air Filtration system connected to my central AC unit in the attic (https://www.aprilaire.com/whole-house-products/air-purifiers/model-2210). I am trying to figure out how often I should change its chunky filter. Recommendation is 9-12 months, but is it 9-12 months of use? I only use this filter for AC and not for heating, so 9-12 months would be at least two summers of AC use - or 2 years. Or does this mean 9-12 months regardless of use, in which case I'd need to replace it before the summer since I installed it last June.

Lastly - the current filter has been there since last June (almost 1 year ago, but only used in AC season) and when I look at it now it looks very clean. Is that an indication of anything?

Thanks for bearing with me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9-12 months is a recommendation. The only way to check a filter accurately is with a dual port manometer

[image]

[Amazon](https://www.google.ca/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwj3x_7Eqp3hAhVqHq0GHc4OAkYYABAIGgJwdg&sig=AOD64_34_eqsfdmbg8vwS-aOuHJN8gHdTQ&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwj6iPTEqp3hAhWLyIMKHf_bANwQwg96BAgLEA8&adurl=)

Nobody is going to buy one of these just to check the filter. Visual and auditory cues are usually enough. If the pleats on the filter are starting to deform it's probably due for a change.

Also keep in mind that ceiling returns tend to pull in less dirt, thus increasing the life expectancy of your attic mounted filter.

All things considered I wouldn't be surprised if you get 3 - 4 years out of the filter. It's dependent on usage and you'll need to monitor it. But don't hesitate to leave a clean and functional filter in because it's old.